# Loading spinner while fetching an api in react app not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the website loads for the first time the fetched data from an api don't show.But after one reload the products are shown . Tried to use a loading spinner while loading the data. The spinner won't show either. How can I show the the loaded data on the first time and while loading the products the Loading spinner will be shown.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


 useEffect(() => {
setIsLoading(true);

fetch(" https://hidden-citadel-3557.herokuapp.com/inventory")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => setInventories(data));
setIsLoading(false );  }, []); `
  if (isLoading) {
return <Loading></Loading>  }
```

Comment: You need to `setLoading(false)` on the final stage of the fetchApi call.

Answer (score 0):

Move "setIsLoading(false)" to the second ".then", like this:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);


 useEffect(() => {
   setIsLoading(true);

fetch(" https://hidden-citadel-3557.herokuapp.com/inventory")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
     setIsLoading(false);
     setInventories(data)
   });
 }, []); 

  if (isLoading) {
return <Loading></Loading>  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, your approach is not a very viable one.

Here's what I would do.

1. Use a separate function for loading the data.

```
function loadData()
{
   setLoading(true);
   fetch(" https://hidden-citadel-3557.herokuapp.com/inventory")
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => {
        setInventories(data);
        setLoading(false);
     });
}
```

2. Then perform your effect:

```
 useEffect(loadData,[]);
```

3. In your jsx, use the `loading` variable to render `<loading>` element based on loading state varibale value:

`{ loading ? <loading></loading> : ""}`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Index = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://627a5a9773bad50685876437.mockapi.io/users"
      );
      await response.json();
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return isLoading ? <p>Loading</p> : <p>Loaded!</p>;
};

export default Index;
```